# In Win10 application using two webview not able to see content if i dont give minHeight to control?

Tags: xaml

Below  is the code snippet:-
 In Below code I am Using two web view control and binding the HTML content by using custom property. Here I want that Web-view content should be displayed without any scroll and automatically fit to grid according to content size.

```
 <Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Name="HtmlSource"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Background="#fffff0">
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtHtmlInput" Width="800" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250"></TextBox>
            <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="COnvert" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content='HTML TO TEXT' Tapped="COnvert_Tapped"></Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <WebView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  x:Name="customWebView" webViewer:MyExtensions.HTML="{Binding Source={StaticResource HtmlSource}, Path=HTML}">
                    </WebView> 

        <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <WebView  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" x:Name="customWebView1" webViewer:MyExtensions.HTML="{Binding Source={StaticResource HtmlSource}, Path=HTML}"></WebView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```